# Custom document class to avoid a lot of boilerplate code?

Tags: macros, environments, document-classes

Can I make a custom document with this structure to avoid all that non-needed builerplate code?

```
\documentclass[Max Mustermann]{article_free}{My usefull header}

\begin{document}

\begin{content}
here is all my content
\end{content}

\end{document}
```

This should generate a full article with title page, table of content page and references on the last page and may avoid custom environment "content" here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "all non-needed boilerplate". Are you claiming that commands such as `\tableofcontents` or `\bibliography` (or, in case you employ biblatex, `\printbibliography`) constitute "boilerplate"? A separate question: Have you considered creating a "standard" preamble that includes the commands needed to compile most (all?) of your documents -- and sticking these commands into a LaTeX package called, say, `mypreamble.sty`, which you'd call in the second line of your LaTeX documents via `\usepackage{mystandardpreamble}`?

Comment: I've often gone the way of creating my `.sty` files as @Mico suggests, but in the end (unless very complex things) I think that having a nice set of template documents is better. I always ended overriding half the commands in the "generic" included file...

Comment: How is the `content` environment defined?

Comment: I have never really understood what is meant by a "template" document/file. If you keep overriding half the commands in the "generic" file then I suspect that you don't have a generic basis. --- GOM

Answer (score 1):

Try along the following idea (untested).

Put all your preamble "boilerplate" in a file classed, say, `preamplebp.tex`.

Put all your "boilerplate" between `\begin{document}` and your `\begin{content}` (whatever that might be) in a file, say, `postamblebp.tex`.

Put all the "boilerplate" (print bibliography, index commands?) between `\end{content}` and `\end{document}` in file `atendbp.tex`.

Then something like:

```
\documentclass....  % a regular class and options
\input{preamblebp}
\title{...}
\date{...}
\begin{document}
\input{postamblebp}
\begin{content}
 HERE IS THE CONTENT
\end{content}
\input{atendbp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That should work OK. I do something similar.